# Syntax error on token "else" delete this token

Tags: android, if-statement

I can't for the life of me fix this. It is returning an error on else. I tried everything on all the other threads that had the same problem, but it didn't work.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { //this method is used for handling menu items' events
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.goBack:
            if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            }
            return true;

            else 
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);{

                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that how your code actually looks when you're editing it? With no indenting? No wonder you're having problems.

Comment: Yes it does. Will that cause it to fail?

Comment: Well, no, the Java compiler doesn't care. But it makes it very difficult for *you* to see how the code blocks actually line up. The result is that you have curly braces in the wrong places, which is causing this error.

Comment: Your `if` condition is already _done_ since you have a statement after the `if` clause that reads `return true;`.  Depending upon what you're trying to achieve, you might want to place it one of the blocks.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation a bit -- as mentioned in the previous comment, your code is clearly broken.

Comment: The code is suppose to allow the back button to work in webView.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is complaining because the else statement does not follow an if statement -- there's a `return true` in between (which by the way prevents any code after it from being executed). Fixing your indentation and code formatting helps discover (and also prevent) simple mistakes like this.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.goBack:
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because in java (and most-likely any programming language that defines `if...else` blocks such as c#, c, c++, etc.) the `else` block (if present) must come right after an `if` block or an `else if` statement definition any other statement between the `if` and `else` is illegal. However, you have a `return` statement right before the `else` block which is illegal and useless because any code blocks after a `return` statement becomes "unreachable"

You can change your code to...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.goBack:
            if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        break;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```